# LWC dropdown not disappearing when clicked on the screen flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I have a LWC in the screen flow. The LWC displays a dropdown list. When I click outside the LWC the dropdown should disappear.How can I enable. I tried onblur, but it is not working.

```
<template>
    <div >
        <lightning-input label="Street" placeholder="Enter the address to search"
            onchange={handleChange} value={locationRecord.CT_Street__c} name = "CT_Street__c"></lightning-input> 
    </div>
    <div if:true={showOptions} role="listbox" 
        class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-card an-custom-option-list slds-is-absolute">
        <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
            <template for:each={places} for:item="place">
                <div key={place.magicKey}>
                    <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item"
                        data-address={place.text} data-name={place.text} data-magickey={place.magicKey}
                        onclick={handleSelect} >
                        <div class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small slds-media_center"
                            role="option">
                            <span class="slds-media__figure">
                                <lightning-icon size="small" icon-name="standard:location">
                                </lightning-icon>
                            </span>
                            <span class="slds-media__body slds-p-left_x-small">
                                <p>{place.text}</p>
                                <p class="slds-text-body-title slds-text-color_weak">
                                    {place.text}
                                </p>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a click listener to the `window` and use it to close the dropdown.

You add the listener only when the dropdown opens, and it removes itself when it closes the dropdown

```
handleClick(event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  this.openDropdown();
  window.addEventListener("click", this.handleClose);
}
handleClose = (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  this.closeDropdown();
  window.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClose);
};
```

Put the listener on the input that causes the dropdown to show, I think, your case, this:

```
<lightning-input label="Street" onclick={handleClick}....
```

Of course, since this is in a flow I'm not totally sure of how events are going to propagate, but as long as you have access to `window` you should be ok.